# Oracle ORDS - Can I control the Transfer-Encoding?

Tags: oracle, api, transfer-encoding

Please note I'm new to APIs and ORDS.

I've created a few APIs with Oracle Rest Data Services (ORDS) which returns 30,000 records at a time. I've noticed in the return header that *Transfer-Encoding* is **chunked**.

Another similar API has *Transfer-Encoding* set to **gzip** - this reduces the size from more than 14Mb to 8Mb (and increases performance). Is this setting in my control when configuring the API with ORDS? How do I set this please?

Comment: If ORDS Handler has ETag it will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found the solution:

```
OWA_UTIL.mime_header('application/json', FALSE);
HTP.p('Transfer-Encoding: gzip');
OWA_UTIL.http_header_close;
```